# How to handle pop up of type windows for which I am not able to find its Xpath or css through firebug

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

On clicking the browse button this pop up comes and I want to browse some files, select that file and click on open and that files path will be saved.

Please find the HTML code for that pop up which I want to handle.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "file" id ="file" name ="files[]" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Selenium cannot handle modal dialogues! See AutoIt, Sikuli, Robot, or any other tool that is used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the path try this:

```
WebElement filepath=driver.findElement(By.id("file"));
filepath.sendKeys("C:\\TextFile.txt");
```

If you want to test the actual browsing you should use [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class to interact with the file dialog, but this is very tricky.

Hope help!

Answer (score 0):

use this to browse a file `driver.findElement(By.id("file")).click().sendKeys("filepath");`